# Taking a screenshot and pasting it to Paint on Windows 8(?) is not working

Tags: gaming, screenshot, windows-8-games

I'm trying to screenshot a website.

I am trying to screenshot https://joezeng.github.io/endless-sans/, which I had a high score of 133.29 seconds on. (I want proof of my accomplishment.)

My laptop is Toshiba and is Windows 8 or Windows 8.1.

How do I get a screenshot of the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Screenshot your whole screen, it's as simple as pressing the "prt sc" key on your keyboard. If you only want a certian part, you can search in start for "snipping tool" and grap a certian portion only. Then press the "copy" button after the screenshot from snipping tools.

No matter which method you chose, the next step is to open Paint and make sure the "select" tool is the selected one. Press ctrl+v and it should be pasted!

Comment: This works great for screens, but if you're trying to grab an entire website (i.e. a shot of everything even if you had to scroll down), it won't work. At that point, you need a browser plugin or other external tool.

Comment: oh, if that's the goal, then I've used this method before and then stitched the multiple images together in gimp (or i suppose you could do it in paint too

Answer (score -1):

Just use <kbd>Print screen</kbd> - this will copy a screenshot of your currenttly opened windows into your clipboard. Then in Paint, just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the screenshot of the image into the canvas.

Answer (score -1):

With the `Snipping tool`, Windows offers a program that can capture windows, the whole screen, or rectangular/... portions of the screen. As this is an external application (unlike <kbd>Print</kbd>), this usually also works for browser windows.

It comes preinstalled with Windows: Just open your Start Menu and search for `Snipping Tool`.

Comment: dear -1 - voter(s): why?